# Powerapps Compare two datetimevalue

Tags: powerapps, power-platform, expressionbuilder

How do you compare two DateTimeValue in PowerApps Expression Builder? I'm doing something like this:

```
DateTimeValue("3/28/2023 7:10 AM") >= DateTimeValue("3/28/2023 9:10 AM")
```

But I'm getting all sorts of weird results, and can't debug completely because it's in the onchange of a dropdown. I want to make sure this is the way to compare date time values.

Comment: That comparison should work (in your case it should always return false, assuming that it is being done in a locale with that date/time format). Can you elaborate on what the "weird results" are?

Comment: PowerApps has a DateDiff() function, are you getting the same 'weird' results with DateDiff(A,B) >= 0? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-dateadd-datediff